# Button opening Form2 is aborting main thread (not intended)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, graphics

**Confirmed problem: My bricks pattern button is running the code in my exit button for some unknown reason**

```
    private void brickToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (f2 != null) return;
        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myThread.Abort();
        Close();
    }
```

I am creating this brick breaker game that has a thread for the main window (paddle and bricks included) and a thread for the ball movement. In my program, if I click on the button to open form2, the entire program just terminates because it is running the code of another button.

Is there another way of opening form2 that won't terminate my program? I have tried different types of Show like `ShowDialog` and in that case, I see the form2 for a quarter of a second. And then the entire program terminates.

This is a link to my form1 code. http://pastebin.com/FB19qd7e
Form1 designer code : http://pastebin.com/RS8VZT5U

EDIT: The output shows this

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>       An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Okay, I have three buttons, an exit, pause, and bricks(which opens form2). The pause button works as intended, and so does the exit. However, if I click the bricks button, for some reason it runs the Thread.Abort from the exit button. If I comment out the exit button code, then the bricks button works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you run with "break on all exceptions" enabled? also, you don't suggest *where* you're adding that code, and that will make a significant difference to the program's behaviour.

Comment: I am just running the program normal. Would it be enabled in a property somewhere? As for where I am adding the code, I just wanted a button to bring up a new form. And I can create a new project and get it working to bring up another form, but in this specific project, it isn't working.

Comment: Press ctrl-alt-e in vs and the exceptions dialogue will open. Check the boxes next to cli exceptions and the debugger will break on any exception, which might help you identify the problem.

Comment: Okay this is interesting. I have 2 buttons in my dropdown menu, a form2 button and an exit button. Apparently, if I click either button, the program runs the code for both buttons. When I commented out the code for the exit button, my second form worked. Why is this happening?

Comment: My pause button works fine. Yet if I click the form2 button, it decides to abort the thread running form1.

Comment: You should probably post some code.  Preferably a concise but complete example that shows exactly what's happening.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? I posted my entire form1 code in the pastebin link above. My form2 is just an empty form. As for an example of what is happening: opening form2 makes the code in the exit button run as well. Both the Thread.Abort() and Close();

Comment: Can you post the content of the Form1.Designer.cs file? Preferably also on pastebin.

Comment: Yes. http://pastebin.com/RS8VZT5U . I have not actually touched this file, and not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have connected the `Deactivate` event for `Form1` in the designer to the `exitToolStripMenuItem_Click` event handler.

```
this.Deactivate += new System.EventHandler(this.exitToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

That will call `exitToolStripMenuItem_Click` when your instance of `Form1` looses focus. When you show a new instance of `Form2` your existing instance of `Form1` will no longer be the active form and that will trigger the call to the event handler which in turn will make the call to `Abort`.

Comment: Interesting... I never edited the designer file and I could have sworn I had not touch anything in the exit button properties, but I probably did. Thanks